# If I got java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, Can I figure out whether it is server problem or connectivity problem?

Tags: web-services, wcf, connection, timeout, soapui

While I was using SoapUI to connect to a WCF service over the internet using HTTP (basicHttpBinding), I got java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

This exception means that SaopUI failed to read the whole message within a time window. Is there a way to determine whether it was a connectivity problem or the server did not respond at all?

Maybe if the client and\or the server sent some packets to each other to check the connection or something like this, I'd now where is the problem.  I believe that some protocols do this but I'm not sure whether basicHttpBinding do this.

I actually don't have any problem anymore, I simply increased the sendTimeout in the client configuration and everything become fine.  However, I am asking whether there is a way to distinguish between connectivity problems and server problems to be able to troubleshoot similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that there might be something wrong with the server. I would like to know the code design on the server-side and the invocation to the service on the client-side.
There are so many factors causing the failure of the client invocation. For example, the client configuration is not correct, binding, authentication mode and so on, the client needs additional credentials, certificates, username/passwords.
Besides, adding the service reference to generate the client proxy and then invocate the service might be a worthy try.
 [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client)
If the issue due to the timeout setup. We could do the below configuration on the basichttpbinding.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"></binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: By the way the client is not affected by "receiveTimeout"

Comment: Yes.  The client is not affection by “receive Timeout”, thanks for your correction.
it is difficult to distinguish the issue is the connectivity problems or the server problems. All the errors due to communication exception might relate to the timeout exception. Just we can do is try to increase some timeout property to check where the problem locates whereas the timeout exception also relates to the server errors.